# Create rule in Outlook to copy email to remote folder?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

We have `Outlook 2013` installed in our `Windows 7` PCs.

In my inbox I'll be receiving a daily email where the subject will include text "Excel Sales for today" and will include an Excel attachment.

Can I create a rule, to run daily, that will take that email and save the attached Excel file to a folder in a remote computer? In my case, it would be copied to `\\RemoteServer\c$\Temp`, but I can also map it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but don't use an Outlook rule. There are many examples of how to do this with a VBA macro. Inside the "ThisOutlookSession" object you can make event triggers to process mail as it comes in, like an Outlook rule does.

The last time I answered this question on StackOverflow was here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637693/outlook-2016-select-script-window-in-rules-wizard-is-blank/51638058#51638058

The answer looks like this:
Put this code in your "ThisOutlookSession" Object. It only works from there.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

' Set up the listener on the Inbox
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

' Send new mail to the attachment processor
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Dim EMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set EMail = Item
        Debug.Print "Incoming Data."
        SaveAttachmentsToDisk EMail
        Set EMail = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)  
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    sSaveFolder = "\\RemoteServer\c$\Temp\"

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.FileName
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would I check if the email subject includes the text "Excel Sales for today"?

Comment: Right before `SaveAttachmentsToDisk EMail`  you would need an `If` statement looking at `Item.Subject`

Comment: Thanks again. When would this macro execute?

Comment: `inboxItems_ItemAdd` is the event handler. It handles the `ItemAdd` event to the `inboxItems` object. (Whenever a new item is added to your inbox)

Comment: Here is the programming reference material: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/using-outlook-visual-basic-for-applications-to-respond-to-outlook-events